# Realtime Dashboard with StreamAnalytics data in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr, dashboard, azure-stream-analytics

Currently i have a EventHub that is receiving Web Events and a stream analytics that is querying them and storing them in an Azure SQL Database table.
In my MVC Dashboard i used EntityFramework to create a model "Events" in database first, i then scaffolded and created the controller and views and currently my dashboard at "localhost:xxxx/Events" shows a table with all the events.

What i want to do is to have them being updated in realtime, preferably using Signal R. The problem i'm stuck with is that SQLDependency doesn't work with Azure sql, and i don't know any other way to achieve my goal of a real time table.

I've tried PowerBI, but i haven't found a console-like realtime table graph and i will be adding buttons  to my dashboard to send post requests to the stream analytics so mvc is the way to go.

This seems simple enough but i'm at it for way too much time, all help is appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not very experienced with Event Hubs, but buy reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn789972.aspx) it looks like there are a couple of options for subscribing to them. If you could use, for example, the **Direct Consumer** strategy, from the reading loop you could easily use SignalR to push data to connected clients. Does this make sense or am I missing something big?

Comment: that would be a way to do it, IF i can't get it to work with azure SQL, i would like signal R to update clients ON database change. If this is not possible then i would try the event hub reading approach.

Comment: still looking for a solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

If your MVC backend is in Java, C#, or C, then I'd recommend having Stream Analytics output the processed data to another Event Hub. Then using C#, C, or Java to subscribe and listen to that Event Hub asynchronously. The messages that go through that new Event Hub will be in real time.

Event Hub #1 -> Stream Processor -> Event Hub #2 -> MVC Webpage